# Adding Windows to Buttons on Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to Python, I'm trying to add widgets in an window which can be used when we click on an button when in Tkinter GUI.

I'm unable to add an window into the GUI button and I'm doubtful about the Code which can be Implemented as well. I hope I could get some inputs on this.

I'm running on IDLE 3.6.3.I would be grateful if someone could point out the additions that could be made and the changes in the current code.

```
ConnectLogo=PhotoImage(file="Connect.png")
Connect  = Button(win,image=ConnectLogo,text = "Connect", font = myFont,height =100 , width = 100,compound=TOP,bg = "orange") 
Connect.grid(row=3,column=1,padx=50,pady=40)

FrequencyLogo=PhotoImage(file="Frequency.png")
Frequency = Button(win,image=FrequencyLogo, text = "Frequency", font = myFont, height = 100, width =180,compound=TOP,bg = "Yellow")
Frequency.grid(row=3,column=2,padx=10)

MaskLogo=PhotoImage(file="Mask.gif")
Mask = Button(win,image=MaskLogo, text = "Mask", font = myFont, height = 100, width =180,compound=TOP,bg = "yellow")
Mask.grid(row=6,column=2,padx=10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function, which will implement TopLevel.
This creates a new window into which you can add widgets, add them inside the function.Inside the function you root becomes `window`

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def new_window():
    window = TopLevel(root)
    ...widgets like label, entry etc
    label = Label(window,....)

btn = Button(...., command = new_window)
btn.pack()...(anything)
```